# How do I find logs that report the cause of a system crash?

Tags: system, reboot, log, crash

My computer with Trusty is often rebooting, apparently in a random way. I have looked in system register but there are so many logs that is quite difficult to find the ones which only report the error that made the system reboot. How can I find only those which caused the reboot?

Answer (score 4):

You can look at the logs leading to the last boot with

```
journalctl -b -1 -e
```

Of course, read `man journalctl` first.

Answer (score 0):

You can begin by checking `/var/log/auth*` logs. Also look at [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9819/how-to-find-out-from-the-logs-what-caused-system-shutdown) for possible reasons.

Comment: So, there is not an easy way to find them, the only one is try and search? The link didn't help much because they were asking about an invoked shoutown/reboot, while I'm asking about a reboot caused by crash, like a system failure, kernel panic and similar things